# Toogle active class using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, toggle

I am trying to change `class` from none to `active` using `document.getElementById` but it is just adding `active` not removing it.

page.html

```js
function toggleIt() {
  let collapseModel = document.getElementById(`collap_id`).className += "content active";
  collapseModel[0].classList.toggle("active")
}
```

```css
.content {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content.active {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleIt();">Open</button>

<div class="content" id="collap_id">
  Here will be all the details
</div>
```

When I click on `toggle it` then it is opening but not closing , it is also showing `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggle')"`

I have tried many times but it is not toggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** `getElementById` will give you single HTML element so no need to use
index.

**2)** You just have to toggle it using `toggle` method

```
function toggleIt() {
  let collapseModel = document.getElementById(`collap_id`);
  collapseModel.classList.toggle("active")
}
```

```js
function toggleIt() {
  let collapseModel = document.getElementById(`collap_id`);
  collapseModel.classList.toggle("active")
}
```

```css
.content {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content.active {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleIt();">Open</button>

<div class="content" id="collap_id">
  Here will be all the details
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposition with using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
const msg = document.querySelector(".content");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  msg.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
  open
</button>

<div class="content" id="collap_id">
  Using querySelector and addEventListener.
</div>
```